# Formula for the Maxwell Stress tensor in arbitrary coordinates

Tags: tensors, index-notation, electromagnetism

This question is nearly identical to my last, except this time its the *Maxwell* stress tensor, not the *Cauchy* stress tensor. I often see its components written as
$$\sigma_{ij}=\varepsilon_0E_iE_j+\frac{1}{\mu_0}B_iB_j+\frac{\delta_{ij}}{2}\left(\varepsilon_0|\boldsymbol E|^2+\frac{1}{\mu_0}|\boldsymbol{B}|^2\right)$$
With $E_i$ being understood as the components of the vector $\boldsymbol E$. But I thought, "hang on", $\boldsymbol E$ is a vector, and thus is contravariant, and its components should be written $E^i$, and similarly for $\boldsymbol B$. But, I **know** that the stress tensor should be fully covariant, since it measures *force* (a vector) per unit *area* (which can be represented as a normal vector). I.e, it takes in two vector inputs and outputs a scalar, so it should be second order covariant. So I thought, we should replace $E_i$ with $g_{ki}E^k$. Similarly, the Kronecker delta bugs me as well - it is defined as a $(1,1)$ tensor, with components
$$\delta^i_j=1 \text{ if }i=j, ~\delta^i_j=0\text{ if }i\neq j$$
So
$$\delta_{ij}=g_{ki}\delta^k_j=g_{ij}$$
So, the "correct" formula, written out in all its glory, should really be
$$\sigma_{ij}=\varepsilon_0(g_{ki}E^k)(g_{lj}E^j)+\frac{1}{\mu_0}(g_{ki}B^k)(g_{lj}B^j)+\frac{g_{ij}}{2}\left(\varepsilon_0|\boldsymbol E|^2+\frac{1}{\mu_0}|\boldsymbol{B}|^2\right)$$
Or of course, in shorter form
$$\sigma_{ij}=\varepsilon_0E_iE_j+\frac{1}{\mu_0}B_iB_j+\frac{g_{ij}}{2}\left(\varepsilon_0|\boldsymbol E|^2+\frac{1}{\mu_0}|\boldsymbol{B}|^2\right)$$
Where $E_i$ are recognized not as the components of $\boldsymbol E$, but rather as the components of $\boldsymbol E^{\flat}$, its dual. And of course $|\boldsymbol E|^2=g_{ab}E^aE^b$. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually better if we define the Lorentz invariant Maxwell stress tensor. It is a second order contravariant tensor:
$$T^{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\left(F^{\alpha\gamma}F^\beta{}_{\gamma}-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\alpha\beta}F^{\gamma\delta}F_{\gamma\delta}\right)$$

Here $F^{\mu\nu}$ is the $\mu,\nu$ component of the field strength tensor and $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the $\mu,\nu$ component of the inverse spacetime metric. This formula works no matter which coordinate system we use (but, the components of $\boldsymbol{\eta}$, $\mathbf{F}$ might be very complicated). We use the well known Lorentz scalar
$$F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}=2|\boldsymbol B|^2-2|\boldsymbol E^2|/c^2$$
Let $i,j,k,l,m\in\{1,2,3\}$. Let's compute the spacial components of the MST:

$$T^{ij}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\left(F^{i\gamma}F^j{}_{\gamma}-\frac{\eta^{ij}}{2}(|\boldsymbol B|^2-|\boldsymbol E^2|/c^2)\right)$$

Working for example in Cartesian spacial coordinates (i.e $\boldsymbol\eta=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$), we have the following identities:
$$F^{i~0}=\frac{1}{c}E^i~~;~~F^{ij}=\varepsilon_{ijk}B^k \\ F^j{}_\gamma=\eta_{\gamma\lambda}F^{j\lambda} \\ \implies F^j{}_0=-F^{j~0}=\frac{-1}{c}E^j \\ \text{and}~~F^j{}_k=\eta_{k\lambda}F^{j\lambda}=\eta_{kk}F^{jk}=\varepsilon_{jkl}B^l$$
Hence
$$T^{ij}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\left(F^{i~0}F^j{}_0+F^{ik}F^j{}_k-\frac{\delta^i_j}{2}(|\boldsymbol B|^2-|\boldsymbol E^2|/c^2)\right) \\ =\frac{1}{\mu_0}\left(-\frac{1}{c^2}E^iE^j+\varepsilon_{ikl}B^l\varepsilon_{jkm}B^m-\frac{\delta^i_j}{2}(|\boldsymbol B|^2-|\boldsymbol E^2|/c^2)\right)$$
Now,
$$\varepsilon_{ikl}\varepsilon_{jkm}=\varepsilon_{ilk}\varepsilon_{jmk}=\delta^i_j\delta^l_m-\delta^i_m\delta^l_j$$
So
$$\varepsilon_{ikl}B^l\varepsilon_{jkm}B^m=(\delta^i_j\delta^l_m-\delta^i_m\delta^l_j)B^lB^m=\delta^i_jB^lB^l-B^iB^j$$
Hence, in Cartesian coords,
$$\boxed{T^{ij}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\left(-\frac{1}{c^2}E^iE^j-B^iB^j+\frac{\delta^i_j}{2}\left(|\boldsymbol B|^2+\frac{1}{c^2}|\boldsymbol E|^2\right)\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

The canonical stress tensor density is given in component form by
$$^ρ_ν = \frac{∂}{∂\left(∂_ρ A_μ\right)} ∂_ν A_μ - δ^ρ_ν ,$$
where $$ is the Lagrangian density that generates the field theory. In terms of the response field (the $$ and $$ fields), which is the tensor density given by
$$^{μν} = -\frac{∂}{∂F_{μν}}$$
where $F_{μν} = ∂_μ A_ν - ∂_ν A_μ$ is the field strength (the $$ and $$ fields), it is:
$$^ρ_ν = -^{ρμ} ∂_ν A_μ - δ^ρ_ν .$$

The stress tensor density $$ is an adjustment of $$, given by:
$$^ρ_ν = ^ρ_ν + ∂_μ ^{ρμ}_ν,$$
where the tensor density $$ arises from the Belinfante correction and is given by:
$$^{ρμ}_ν = ^{ρμ} A_ν.$$

The response field is subject to the Euler-Lagrange equations
$$∂_ν ^{μν} = ^μ,$$
where the current density (also a tensor density, as the name indicates) is given by
$$^μ = \frac{∂}{∂A_μ}.$$

Assuming we're talking about the *free field*, i.e. where the current density vanishes, then:
$$∂_ν ^{μν} = ^μ = 0,$$
and the divergence of the Belinfante correction term yields:
$$∂_μ ^{ρμ}_ν = ∂_μ^{ρμ} A_ν + ^{ρμ} ∂_μA_ν = ^{ρμ} ∂_μA_ν.$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
^ρ_ν
&= -^{ρμ} ∂_ν A_μ - δ^ρ_ν  + ^{ρμ} ∂_μA_ν\\
&= ^{ρμ} \left(∂_μA_ν - ∂_ν A_μ\right) - δ^ρ_ν \\
&= ^{ρμ} F_{μν} - δ^ρ_ν .
\end{align}$$
**This only applies for free fields!** If there is a non-zero current density, there is the additional term that arises from it.

For the **Maxwell-Lorentz** Lagrangian density for the free field:
$$ = -\frac{ε_0c}{4} \sqrt{|g|} g^{μρ}g^{νσ}F_{μν}F_{ρσ} = -\frac{ε_0c}{4} \sqrt{|g|} F_{μν}F^{μν},$$
the response field and current density are
$$^{μν} = ε_0c \sqrt{|g|} g^{μρ}g^{νσ}F_{ρσ} = ε_0c \sqrt{|g|} F^{μν},$$
using the metric to raise indices, and the stress tensor density is:
$$^ρ_ν = ε_0c \sqrt{|g|} \left(F^{ρμ} F_{μν} + \frac{1}{4}δ^ρ_ν F^{νσ}F_{νσ}\right).
$$

**Generically**, one can write the following component forms adapted to the coordinates
$$x^0 = t, \quad \left(x^1, x^2, x^3\right) = (x,y,z)$$
as:
$$
φ = -A_0, \quad  = \left(A_1, A_2, A_3\right), \quad  = \left(F_{23}, F_{32}, F_{12}\right), \quad  = \left(F_{10}, F_{20}, F_{30}\right),\\
ρ = ^0, \quad  = \left(^1, ^2, ^3\right), \quad  = \left(^{01},^{02}, ^{03}\right), \quad  = \left(^{23}, ^{31}, ^{12}\right),
$$
with
$$ρ = -\frac{∂}{∂φ}, \quad  = +\frac{∂}{∂}, \quad  = +\frac{∂}{∂}, \quad  = -\frac{∂}{∂},$$
and (in tensor-dyad form):
$$
^0_0 = · - , \quad \left(^1_0, ^2_0, ^3_0\right) = ×, \quad
\left(^0_1, ^0_2, ^0_3\right) = ×,\\
^i_j = D^iE_j + B^iH_j - δ^i_j(· + ) = \left( +  - (· + )\right)^i_j\quad (i,j = 1, 2, 3).
$$

The trace is:
$$^μ_μ = 2(· - ·) - 4 = 2\left(·\frac{∂}{∂} + ·\frac{∂}{∂} - 2\right).$$
This shows that a free field with a trace-free stress tensor can only arise from a free field Lagrangian that is homogeneous to the second degree in the field strengths. If it is also Lorentz invariant, then it is a function that is homogeneous to the first degree in the field invariants:
$$ℑ_0 ≡ \frac{||^2 - ||^2c^2}{2}, \quad ℑ_1 ≡ ·,$$
expressible as
$$ = ε ℑ_0 + θ ℑ_1 = ε \frac{||^2 - ||^2c^2}{2} + θ ·,$$
where the derivatives of the Lagrangian density
$$ε ≡ \frac{∂}{∂ℑ_0}, \quad θ ≡ \frac{∂}{∂ℑ_1},$$
are constant: $ε = ε_0$ and $θ = θ_0$. The term $θ ·$ is a boundary term and can be eliminated, which reduces the Lagrangian density to the form:
$$ = ε_0 \frac{||^2 - ||^2c^2}{2},$$
which is exactly what the Maxwell-Lorentz Lagrangian density is. The response fields, for this Lagrangian density are:
$$ = ε_0 , \quad  = ε_0c^2 ,$$
and the components of the stress tensor density reduce to:
$$
^0_0 = ε_0\frac{||^2 + ||^2c^2}{2}, \quad \left(^1_0, ^2_0, ^3_0\right) = ε_0×c^2, \quad
\left(^0_1, ^0_2, ^0_3\right) = ε_0×,\\
^i_j = ε_0\left( + c^2 - \frac{||^2 + ||^2c^2}{2}\right)^i_j\quad (i,j = 1, 2, 3).
$$

This generalizes to gauge fields, except that the potentials $A^a_μ$, field strengths $F^c_{μν}$, response fields $_c^{μν}$ and current density $_a^μ$ now all have an extra index, referring to a Lie algebra basis (for $A$ and $F$) or dual basis (for $$ and $$).

The expression of $F$ in terms of $A$ and the Euler-Lagrange equations that express $$ in terms of $$ may be non-linear - as they are if the underlying Lie algebra is non-Abelian - but the expressions for the stress tensor density are of the same form, e.g. $^0_0 = _a·^a - $.

The role played by $ε_0c$ is then played by the Lie algebra metric $k_{ab}$, whose specification is also part of the specification of the gauge field. The analogue of the Maxwell-Lorentz Lagrangian density, then, is precisely what the Yang-Mills Lagrangian density is,
$$ = -\frac{k_{ab}}{4} \sqrt{|g|} g^{μρ}g^{νσ}F^a_{μν}F^b_{ρσ}.$$

For both Maxwell-Lorentz and Yang-Mills, the term
$$\sqrt{|g|} g^{μρ}g^{νσ}$$
is independent of which scaling convention (and sign) you use for the metric $g_{μν}$ and its inverse $g^{μν}$ and all the expressions are convention-independent, as is the stress tensor density.

If, on the other hand, you take out the $\sqrt{|g|}$ to get the stress tensor
$$T^ρ_ν = \frac{^ρ_ν}{\sqrt{|g|}}, \quad T_{μν} = g_{μρ}T^ρ_ν,$$
then it *will* depend on what convention you use for the metric, as well as for the coordinates.

So, there's really no consistent form for the stress tensor - it's convention-dependent and author-dependent. Only the stress tensor density transcends all that and only it is directly connected to the various quantities involved in the integrals that densities are integrands for.